# how to draw 3D figure when using list data in python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I know the best way is trying function Z = f(X, Y) and then using X,Y,Z,but my actual data is stored in a list，here I just give a simple example.

I want take i, j and test_list as X,Y,Z coordinate:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D 
test_list = []

for i in np.arange(1, 21):
    for j in range(1, 11):
        test_list.append(i * j)
```

so at first the shape of test_list is (200,) and then I reshape it as (20,10) and using meshgrid:

```
i = np.array(np.arange(1, 21))
j = np.array(np.arange(1, 11))

X, Y = np.meshgrid(i, j)

Z1  =  np.reshape(test_list, (20, 10))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z1, rstride=1, cstride=1,
                cmap='viridis', edgecolor='none')

plt.show()
```

However it shows error:

> shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape

How to solve it, I guess there is no problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. You create `Z1` as shape `(20, 10)`, however `meshgrid` creates `X` and `Y` as `(10, 20)`. The solution is to transpose the array:

```py
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z1.T, rstride=1, cstride=1,
                cmap='viridis', edgecolor='none')
```